# How to access org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl.JvmTarget in buildSrc folder?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, kotlin-dsl, buildsrc

In my Android/Gradle project in the `buildSrc` folder I like to provide a property which returns the data type `org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl.JvmTarget` in the `buildSrc` folder. The build configuration for this folder currently looks like this:

```kotlin
plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Which plugin/dependency do I have to add to get access to `org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl` data types?

Answer (score 0):

To access `org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl.JvmTarget` and other types related to the Kotlin plugin in normal Kotlin files (including Kotlin files in the `buildSrc` project), you should add the [Kotlin Gradle plugin JAR](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin) to the classpath:

```
dependencies {
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.9.22") 
}
```

Note that doing this in the `buildSrc` `build.gradle.kts` file adds the Kotlin plugin to the classpath of all `build.gradle.kts` files in the project, which means you will need to remove references to the version to other applications of the Kotlin plugin elsewhere in the build to avoid a Gradle error.

This also means that the version you specify in such a way in a `buildSrc` project will define the Kotlin plugin version throughout your project.

Comment: I like to expose the property from a Kotlin file as drafted [here](https://github.com/EventFahrplan/EventFahrplan/commit/4bc700dae339501f8fb6e1737977fd93f9e0ba37). There the dependency cannot be resolved, though.

Comment: Ah, ok. I had misinterpreted your question. Now changed to cover regular Kotlin files.

Comment: Thank you for the rewrite. Adding the dependency to the project results in the following error: `Failed to apply plugin 'kotlin-android'. Could not create an instance of type org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.KotlinAndroidTarget.` Removing other `org.jetbrains.kotlin` references doesn't help.

Comment: Classloader issues probably. I would put `plugins { id("kotlin-android") apply false }` in the root `build.gradle` file

Comment: I am still using the `classpath` and `apply plugin` syntax in [my project](https://github.com/EventFahrplan/EventFahrplan). I could not find out how to use `apply false` in that setup.

Comment: I think adding the JAR to the `classpath` configuration has the same effect, so you are already there now I look at your project. I would think another way to avoid the clash is to put the Kotlin Gradle plugin in `compileOnly` rather than `implementation` in the `buildSrc` `build.gradle.kts` file

Comment: Do you mean adding `dependencies { compileOnly("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.9.22") }` to `buildSrc/build.gradle.kts`? That fails as well as removing the `plugins` block additionally.

Comment: Hmm don't know I'm afraid. I'd be trying updating Gradle and clearing caches next.